# build android app using intellij idea cannot find theme AppCompat.Light

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Now I am trying to build this android app using this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) . but when I add the example code below I got an error.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

the error is :

```
AndroidManifest.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given
name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light').
```

I have tried many post on the internet but I didn`t find solutions about using intellij idea.

and all my code is here, but I think this is not the problem it must be something I forgot to config using idea :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.androidtwo"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

activity

```
package com.example.androidtwo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your build.gradle has to contain this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
```

Comment: I did not use gradle, but I have already import the appcompat dependency and make it as an module in my project.

Comment: how did you add the dependency? I think this is your problem. You MUST add it as an library project - not just the classes as jar

Comment: yes I add it as an library. first I import the appcompat project as an module and then I make the jar files in libs dir as an library. Is there any other thing I should do?

Comment: yea - this is your problem - the jar does not contain the styles - just the logic classes - you need to add it as a library project - perhaps think about using gradle - this way it is very easy

Comment: by the way, where can I search gradle dependency? I know maven has this website search.maven.org